# Connectiong two virtual box vms to interface

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am new to virtua box I am running virtual box in ubuntu 16.04 i have created two vms vm1 and vm2 now my host on which virtual box is installed is connected to wlp2s0  now i want to connect my vm1 and vm2 to this wlps20 network so the the following is the procedure followed by me

settings->network->Adapter1->Attached to bridge adapter and name wlp2s0(my wifi network to which host is connected) ->ok

but when i login into vm1 and do ifconfig i cant see it connected to wlp2s0

I tried advanced  altered options but it didnt work